# when login user tenantId is null, creatoruserId is not auto inserted?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

when login user with tenant Id is null, I insert data in table and creator user id is not auto inserted login user id value in asp.net core boilerplate 6.5. I'm using multitenancy. I want to auto inserted creator user id value

I want to know why can't auto inserted and is it possible to auto insert creator user id

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.